# Alert comes out even though it is not alert

Tags: jquery, ajax

i am trying to make a upload image using `ajaxform`. My code is working fine but i have a alert problem. I am not giving any `alert();` in the following code you can see. But after uploaded the image then it shows me `alert`. What could be the reason for this?

```
$('body').on('change', '#storyImg', function() { 
    $("#storyForm").ajaxForm({
      beforeSubmit: function() {
        $(".shareStorie").append('<div class="spinnerUploadG"></div>');
      },
      success: function(response) {
        $(".spinnerUploadG").remove(); 
        // No Alert Here
      },
      error: function() {
        return false;
      }
    }).submit();
  });
```

Comment: Confirm your file that you saved is right or not? Put your alert in success so you can check this code executed or another.

Comment: @Sadikhasan I already confirming the file. After the confirm i get the alert. I really don't understand where it will be come.

Comment: what you get in your alert?

Comment: @Sadikhasan **Your Image Uploaded SuccessFully!** It will be come from php code, if upload success.

Comment: Find this message **Your Image Uploaded SuccessFully!** from your whole project and remove it

Comment: @Sadikhasan I have removed that then i get empty alert :S

Comment: Once try in **Private window browser** may be retrieved from cache

Comment: @Sadikhasan Tryed now and i get same alert.